# Argparse optional required arguments produce error if missing, but the action is still performed

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following snippet:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--p', required=True)
parser.add_argument('arg', action=MyAction)
parser.parse_args()
```

, where `MyAction` is a simple custom action class.

As you see, I want to enforce the presence of the `p` argument. However, my action is performed even if the argument is not present, and then an error message is shown that indicates the fact the the argument is missing.

Obviously, I could check in my action class for the presence of the `p` argument, but this defies the purpose of having a `required` parameter in the first place. Why is my action being run if the argument is not present?

Comment: As written, `MyAction` has to be performed as part of parsing the arguments. Even if the argument parser eventually rejects your command, it's still done a bunch of parsing, because it doesn't know your command is bad until it has tried to parse it. If you don't want `MyAction` to be run as part of parsing, maybe you should call it explicitly after parsing has finished.

Comment: But shouldn't it parse the optional argument first? Or the order of parsing is not guranteed?

Comment: I presume it parses all the arguments it is given in the command, and then looks at whether the result constitutes a valid command.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing is driven by the commandline strings, and tries to be order agnostic. Within those rules, it alternates between parsing an `optional` and a `positional`.

For example, with `myprog --p one two`:

- '--p' - pass the 'one' string to the `p` action (e.g. `setattr(namespace, 'p', 'one')`
- 'two' - matches the `nargs` for 'arg'.  Calls your `MyAction.__call__` with `values='one'`.
- at the **end** of parsing it checks if all required actions have been 'seen'.  With your setup both '--p' and 'arg' are required.

With `myprog two --p one` it does the same, except `arg` is processed first.  The `namespace` may have a default value for `p`.

With `myprog two`, `arg` is processed, and the `required` test will raise an  error. `error: the following arguments are required: --p`

Since you have written a custom Action, you can easily explore how the `namespace` contents vary depending on the commandline arguments and their order.

So the `--p` and the `arg` will be processed independently, and in either order, depending on the commandline strings.  `required` testing is performed at the end, using a list of `seen_actions`.  And default values are set at the start of parsing.  It is difficult to implement reliable inter-action tests within custom Actions.  Usually it is better to perform such tests after parsing.

The defined Actions only change the `args` namespace.  So parsing does not change anything beyond what it returns. Unless there's an error and it forces an `sys.exit`. A custom `MyAction` class can change that, but at your own risk.

Comment: I am aware of the different behavior produced by changing the order of the arguments. I guess there is not much I can do about it, besides checking in my action if I have all the required fields.